The essential supremum of a continuous bounded function
I'm self studying Capinski and Kopp's Measure, Integral, and Probability.
I'm struggling to understand the solution to Exercise 3.6.
The exercise states:

Show that for measurable $f$, $\text{ess sup} f \leq \sup f$.
Show that these quantities coincide when $f$ is continuous.

Here the essential supremum is defined as $\text{ess sup} = \inf \{ z : f \leq z \; \text{almost everywhere} \}.$
Let's assume $\text{ess sup} f \leq \sup f$, we want to prove $\text{ess sup} f = \sup f$ for a continuous bounded $f$.
The book's solution is the following:

Let $f$ be continuous with $\sup f = M$, where $M \in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose $\text{ess sup} f < M$.
Then we can take $z$ between these numbers and by the definition of $\text{ess sup}$, $f(x) \leq z$ almost everywhere.
Hence $A= \{x : f(x) > z\}$ is null.
However, by continuity $A$ contains the set $f^{-1} \left( \left(z, M \right) \right)$ which is open - a contradiction.

Is the idea that if the set $f^{-1} \left( \left(z, M \right) \right)$ has non-zero measure, then it cannot be a subset of a null set?
I would find it very useful if someone could expand on this solution, and spell the contradiction out a little more, because I'm not getting it.

A non-empty open set cannot have Lebesgue measure $0$.
